# My neural network is good learning products but fails for sums

Tags: neural-networks, intuition, numpy

I implemented a simple feed-forward neural network with biases trained with backpropagation and stochastic gradient decent. What surprises me is how differently is behaves on two datasets I generated.

```
# Product dataset
inputs = np.random.rand(100000, 10)
targets = np.column_stack([np.prod(inputs, axis=1)])

# Sum dataset
inputs = np.random.rand(100000, 10)
targets = np.column_stack([np.sum(inputs, axis=1)])
```

For the products, the networks quickly converges to an error close zero while it doesn't make much progress on the sums. Note that in the charts, the error on the current batch is plotted rather than evaluating the whole test set every time.

[image: errors on product dataset]

[image: errors on sum dataset]

I played with parameters like learning rate, batch size and weight initialization. Tweaking the parameters doesn't seem to have a big impact on the relative performance on the two datasets. This is the configuration I used to produce the charts:

```
Layer sizes:           10, 15, 15, 1
Activation function:   Sigmoid
Loss function:         Sum of squared errors
Initial weights:       Gaussian with scale 0.1
Learning rate:         1e-3
Batch size:            100
Rounds on the dataset: 5
```

Is the problem of finding sums of inputs conceptually harder than finding products for multi-layer perceptrons? My intuition is the other way around: Trivial weights can just pass activations from layer to layer unchanged and they get summed up for the output neuron. For multiplication, I don't see a trivial weight pattern. On the other hand, I don't know if my implementation is correct.

Comment: Are you sure your gradient calculation is correct?

Comment: What types of nodes are being used internally?

Comment: @jlimahaverford Sigmoid. Added that to the description.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Very possible. I couldn't find anything tough. [Here is my code.](https://github.com/danijar/ffnn)

Comment: With the sigmoid activation units your idea that "Trivial weights can just pass activations from layer to layer unchanged" is not possible.  This does not explain why products is doing better than sums though, in my mind.

Comment: @jlimahaverford Ahh, good call! This lead me to the solution. In contrast to the products the sums can get larger than one so the sigmoidial output neuron has a hard time predicting it :D

Comment: making it an answer if you don't mind :)

Comment: @jlimahaverford Sure, go ahead. After normalizing my data, the neural network gets close to 100% accuracy. This a graph for predicting both sums and products at the same time: http://i.imgur.com/16T7dtb.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a sigmoid units everywhere and 10 inputs that are uniformly distributed between [0,1] then, while their product will be in [0,1], their sum will most likely not be, guaranteeing a certain amount of error.

P.S. - To be honest, I'm confused as to why the error is as low as it is.

Comment: Always normalize your data. Lesson learned :) Thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: Can you also try using linear units?

Comment: For ReLU less and less neurons get activated after some training and for the identity activation functions, gradients get huge and overflow after some training. Both don't work very well. Suggestions are welcome. (If I cancel training before the gradients get huge, the identity activation functions [get a very small error](http://i.imgur.com/uYMoLrK.jpg).)

Comment: That seems absurd.  I will be thinking about that a lot!

Comment: I got the formula for backpropagation wrong in a way that it didn't affect learning with sigmoids. However, identity and ReLU don't learn anything. I tried very small learning rates but it doesn't help. Do you have some advice on how to train with those activation functions? Can I use them as for the output layer as well?

Comment: Yes, you can use them as the output layer.